# SQL query for below input and output?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

[image]

[OUTPUT TABLE NEEDED] -

```
Amount  StartDate   EndDate
27000   2020-06-01  2020-06-04
32000   2020-06-05  2020-06-06
37000   2020-06-06  2020-06-07
```

something like this.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

How are StartDate and EndDate related? The graphic does not show these columns. Also please show us what you have already tried and what exactly the question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like you're looking for a standard `Gaps-and-Islands`.

However, I'm not sure I agree with your desired results.   Perhaps I'm missing a requirement.

Also, in the FUTURE, please don't paste sample data as images... most would rather copy & paste.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([TransDate] date,[Amount] int)  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('2020-06-01',27000)
,('2020-06-02',27000)
,('2020-06-03',27000)
,('2020-06-04',27000)
,('2020-06-05',32000)
,('2020-06-06',37000)
,('2020-06-07',27000)
,('2020-06-08',47000)
 
 Select [Amount]
       ,StartDate = min(TransDate)
       ,EndDate   = max(TransDate)
 From  (
        Select *
              ,Grp = datediff(DAY,'1900-01-01',TransDate) - row_number() over (partition by Amount order by TransDate)
         From @YourTable
       ) A
 Group By Amount,Grp
 Order By min(TransDate)
```

**Returns**

```
Amount  StartDate   EndDate
27000   2020-06-01  2020-06-04
32000   2020-06-05  2020-06-05
37000   2020-06-06  2020-06-06
27000   2020-06-07  2020-06-07
47000   2020-06-08  2020-06-08
```

Comment: Thanks for the grouping logic.
Do you know any source where I can find these type of SQL questions for practice?

Comment: @BhardwajShivam Always happy to help,  Regarding additional sources, no I don't.  I do suggest that you follow this site.  I learn something every day  :)